# How to import data to a vector in R

Tags: r, csv, vector, import

I would like to import CSV data into R in the form of an object of one dimension such as a vector. I only manage to import my data in the form of a table. I tried to convert the table into a vector, however it is not only challenging to my lack of expertise in R but also seems to lack parsimony for such a basic function.

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this basic task, similar to the way c(x,y,z,...) works?

My data looks like the following (with 24,000 values):
1417656631000,0,0,3,20450,2,7,30798,2,2,7449,3,5,16002,2,1,77666,2,8,7435,4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `scan`

```
 op <- options(scipen=999)
 res <- scan('yourfile.csv', what=numeric(), sep=",", quiet=TRUE)
 res
 #[1] 1417656631000             0             0             3         20450
 #[6]             2             7         30798             2             2
 #[11]          7449             3             5         16002             2
 #[16]             1         77666             2             8          7435
 #[21]             4
```